# Installing Desktop on Vagrant Centos Box Breaks Private Network and Shared Folder

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a CentOS 6.5 box created using Vagrant 1.7.2 with VirtualBox 4.3.20.

After doing vagrant up, installing the VirtualBox 4.3.20 Guest Additions and then a vagrant reload: the shared folder is still good and Vagrant can SSH into the box successfully using the private network.

If I then install Centos Desktop using:

```
yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop"
```

On vagrant reload - the shared folder is now empty and the private network IP address has changed to the public IP address, stopping the SSH connection for Vagrant.

Why does the Desktop install do this? Is it a Vagrant/VirtualBox issue or a Desktop install issue?

Vagrantfile is below:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"
  config.vm.hostname = "arcgistux"

  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.11.164.56", :netmask => "255.255.252.0"

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "setup.sh" 

  config.vm.synced_folder "sync-folder/", "/vagrant"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Load the command line GUI
    vb.gui = true

    # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 4]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "8192"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "256"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--clipboard", "bidirectional"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--draganddrop", "bidirectional"]

    # Network settings
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnspassdomain2", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver2", "on"]
  end
end
```

Comment: You should still be able to ssh to the box by using 127.0.0.1:2222 as default network (NAT) is in place. Installing X Window System / desktop environment may bring in NetworkManager which may change the way that the network interfaces are configured. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks Terry - disabling NetworkManager was it.  Still learning Linux!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable NetworkManager using the instructions [here](http://xmodulo.com/disable-network-manager-linux.html).

1 - Stop the NetworkManager service:

```
service NetworkManager stop
```

2 - Disable it

```
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

3 - Edit */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*

Replace

```
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
```

with

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

4 - Restart the Network service

```
service network restart
```

Comment: BTW - the shared folders weren't working because the networking error was preventing the Vagrantfile from executing fully.  Fixing the networking also fixed the missing shared folder